# Covariance in c# is not type safe. This statement applies fine when dealing with arrays, but not when dealing with Ienumerables. Why?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

Case 1 : Covariance in arrays.

```
object[] array = new String[10];
// The following statement produces a run-time exception.  
array[0] = 10;
```

Case 2 : Covariance in IEnumerable.

```
IEnumerable<Object> l1 = new List<string>();
// The following line executes just fine.
l1 = l1.Append(33);
```

We are implementing same scenario, i.e. putting an object of Array/List of more derived type (string), in a variable of less derived type (object), and then trying to add an element of type int.

### Another related observation:

Consider we have following set of classes:

```
public class Bird { }
public class Pegion : Bird { }

public class BirdCalculations<T>
{
    private T TField;
    public void SetTField(T value)
    {
        this.TField = value;
    }
}
```

In this scenario, consider the following code:

```
public static void Main() {
    BirdCalculations<Bird> bc2 = new BirdCalculations<Pegion>();    //Line 1

    BirdCalculations<Bird> bc1 = new BirdCalculations<Bird>();
    bc1.SetTField(new Pegion());    //Line 2

    //Now, Line 2 makes sense, but what is the problem with Line 1?
}
```

Comment: What's that `Append()` method?

Comment: @haim770 Enumerable.Append - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netcore-3.1...

Comment: `Append` is an extension method that doesn't modify the original list. You're discussing two very different scenarios that aren't related.

Comment: Gaurav, could you please clarify how these two examples relate to each other? One tries to modify existing array and another creates new sequence as result of `Append` operation. I don't see much similarities between the two...

Comment: Just because `Pegion` inherits from `Bird` it does not mean that `BirdCalculations<Pegion>` inherits from `BirdCalculations<Bird>`. It does not.

Answer (score 1):

If your class is the receiving end of `T`-type parameter e.g. having method `foo(T bar)`, you need a *contravariance* of `T` and not covariance, which is denoted as `in T` in C#. It also has to be an interface or delegate, so it is not possible to allow assignment of  `BirdCalculations<T1>` instance to `BirdCalculations<T2>` reference or vice versa or whatever, no matter how `T1` and `T2` are related. It has to be `IBirdCalculation<T1> bc = new BirdCalculation<T2>()` or something like that. Here is the example modified from your code:

```
public class Bird { }
public class Pegion : Bird { }

public interface IBirdCalculations<in T> {
    void SetTField(T value);
}

public class BirdCalculations<T> : IBirdCalculations<T>
{
    private T TField;
    public void SetTField(T value)
    {
        this.TField = value;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main() {
        IBirdCalculations<Pegion> bc2 = new BirdCalculations<Bird>();    //Line 1

        IBirdCalculations<Bird> bc1 = new BirdCalculations<Bird>();
        bc1.SetTField(new Pegion());    //Line 2
    }
}
```

Notice that you cannot assign an instance of `BirdCalculations<Pegion>` to `IBirdCalculations<Bird>` reference because if that were possible somebody might invoke something like `SetTField(parrot)` and that shouldn't be allowed.

PS: Arrays in C# is not a variance, it is somehow historically allowed to be used like that but it actually breaks type-safe system. My best guess is that it was necessary when we had no generic in .NET which is like 15+ years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Covariance is safe for reading, but not for writing. When using an array, you can set a value in the array to an arbitrary type - this is not type safe, and that's the unwanted type escape. The same way, contravariance is safe for writing, but not for reading. Unfortunately, there were no ways to constrain variance in arrays back when that was implemented, other than making them entirely type invariant - which would severely limit code reuse without generics (just imagine how something like `Array.Sort` would work).

You cannot change an enumerable. Enumerables are read only. You did not add any item to the enumerable, and you didn't "modify" anything inside that enumerable. What `Append` does is create a new `IEnumerable<object>`. There's no type safety violation. To get a mental picture, you can imagine the new enumerable *containing* the old enumerable - but it doesn't change anything. All of the items that the enumerables might return still satisfy the original constraint - they're all `object`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't doing what you think it is;

```
IEnumerable<Object> l1 = new List<string>();
// The following line executes just fine.
l1 = l1.Append(33);
```

First you're assigning a list to l1, as you expect. But then you're calling `IEnumerable<>.Append()` which is equivalent to;

```
        public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T obj)
        {
            foreach (var s in source)
                yield return s;
            yield return obj;
        }
```

In other words, Append create a new `IEnumerable` that can be used to visit each element of your list, then the value you appended.